# How to run the shell script so that it doesn't do anything

Tags: unix

On the interview I received the question "How to run the shell script so that it doesn't do anything". Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: `echo "hi" >/dev/null`

Comment: what about set -v?

Comment: Sure. There can be multiple answers to this. You are only limited by your imagination.

Comment: could you let me know where can I find all commands?

Comment: What is your definition of "doesn't do anything"?
Using -n option like `script -n` just checks the shell script syntax but not really executing the script. So it doesn't do anything except checking the syntax.

Comment: Setting -v will echo the command the script executes in addition to actually running the command.

Comment: If you're offered a position at that company, politely decline - you don't want to work somewhere that considers that to be a good interview question!

Answer (score 1):

Impossible.

Executing a shell script will "do something". We can make what it does very trivial, but it's not possible that *something* doesn't happen.

Executing a shell script will necessitate the operating system to locate the file containing the shell script, open and read the file, check the first line for the shebang, ... The OS is going to start a new process, so a PID is going to get allocated. The point is, executing a shell script is going to do *something*.

It is possible to execute a script without starting a new shell, precede the script with a single dot and a space.

With bash, we can use `bash -n myscript.sh` to check the syntax of the script without actually executing it. But again, it's still doing something (reading the myscript.sh file and the checking syntax.)

Even if we direct stdin, stdout and stderr to /dev/null, the operating system is  still doing something.

Even if we give an invalid name for a shell script, the operating system is going to check to see if the script exists, so it's doing something.

If we take the specification "doesn't do anything" to seriously mean that the operating system does not do *anything*, then it's impossible.